# How can I get Phpstorm to recognize NextJS pages as being used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Here's my fresh NextJS app:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

The problem is, I'm getting this warning from PHPStorm:

> Unused default export

I know I can ignore it like this:

```
// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
export default MyApp
```

And I can ignore at the program level, but it defeats the purpose.

I'm wondering if its possible to create an IDE helper file, or if there's common knowlegde amongst NextJS programmers on how to handle this that I'm not aware of.

I imagine the code that connects these pages exists outside of my project in the compiling business logic, which then makes be believe more that this is a univeral issue for NextJS devs. How Can I get PHPStorm to recognize that these functions are being used?

Comment: Perhaps if you dont use it anywhere, just remove the `export default MyApp` line?

Comment: @kinduser it's used by NextJS, /pages is a default directory and it makes use of any files added there and auto-detects them for the router. PHPStorm just doesnt know about it, and I'm not sure how to make it detect the parent usage.

Answer (score 5):

Create a scope for the pages folder (include recursively)

[image: Step 1]

And disable the rule for only the pages scope

[image: Step 2]